# Within Orthodoxy, is there a dress-code for receiving an aliyah?

Tags: clothing, torah-reading, torah-service

- I was told that when the oleh receives an aliyah he must have his sleeves covering up to his forearm and must be wearing pants. Also, the collar bone cannot be seen. This was derived from something about a grasshopper/cricket who's wings cover the shin bone and forearm. (Anyone have a source?)
- Potential olim must be wearing 'Shabbat appropriate' attire. And if what they're wearing is 'not as good' as what they've warn for Shabbat in past (i.e. one shabbat its a suit and then another time jeans), they are not allowed to get an aliyah. (Side note: I have heard of people receiving an aliyah despite their dress, but I'm not sure if those were non-Orthodox shuls)
- (hopefully still relevant) All attendees, honorees and olim when within the domain of the Aron Kodesh must wear two head coverings (typically kippa and tallit gadol) during public Torah reading.

Please source if possible. Feel free to mention any books/articles that are Torah Service focused, though I presume I'll have to post this as a separate question. Thanks for your time!

Comment: I'm a bit confused what your question is here. Are you simply asking "are these things that I've heard true?"

Comment: Please see the last few mishnayot in tractate megilla

Comment: @Daniel - Yes. Overall wanted to know as well as list if what I've heard is true.

Comment: @DoubleAA Looked into last mishnayot of Tractate Megilla over Shabbat. Didn't see much regarding attire. I think I went as far back as 21a. I think it was 32 or 29 that mentioned not going up naked, but that was it.

Comment: The chapters in the Talmud are in a different order than in the mishna. Check out 4:6 about פוחח

Comment: There is an overall rule that on should be dressed appropriately when coming to the synagogue. I.e. - one should dress as if he were approaching a king, which is, effectively, what you are doing. However, I don't think SC specifies exact clothing other than stating one must not have dirt on his shoes. I'm unaware that jeans and sneakers, if neat, pose any problem, though IMO, one should dress better. As for the rest, I think each shul has its own standards. Years ago, Rav Haskel Lookstein's shul (Is it KAJ?) required men to wear ties to get an aliyah. That may be a problem with Chabad-ers.

Comment: "...He must have his sleeves covering up to his forearm" What about when he's wearing tefillin?